# In SQL, when should I use the GROUP BY clause and how do I determine the elements to add under the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, database

```
SELECT
    usertype,
    CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route,
    COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
    ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration as int64)/60), 2) AS duration
FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY
    start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
    num_trips DESC
LIMIT 100
```

In this code, I need explanation on why the code was grouped by those items there, and whats the literal meaning of that action.

I tried to remove one of the elements under GROUP BY but discovered it produced an error. But I don't know the rationale behind selecting them

Comment: This query provides aggregated statistics on the number of trips and average duration based on different start and end stations and user types

Comment: The query groups by start_station_name, end_station_name, and usertype to aggregate the data. The query is able to calculate the total number of trips (num_trips) and the average duration (duration) for each unique combination. It allows you to analyze the data based on different start and end stations and distinguish the results by the user type.

Comment: Removing any of the columns given in the GROUP BY clause would produce an error because the query is using those columns for aggregation and need them to be included in the grouping.

Comment: It soulds like you need to read some SQL tutorials on aggregations an grouping, there are plenty available in your favourite internet search engine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.